# VFP - Control report from form

Tags: crystal-reports, visual-foxpro

iam using VFP 9.0...Iam making an invoice report, what i want to know is how to change the contents of the report by changing lets say a combo box in a form. or be able to use select and where clause in the report...any help would be appreciated :)

EDITED FOR CLARIFICATION (per comments instead of direct add into question)

```
+-----------------+       +-------------------------+
|  Contract Form  |       |   Invoice Form          |
|                 |       |                         |
|                 |       | radioCustomer           |
| btnInvoiceForm -------> |    comboCustomersList   |
+-----------------+       | radioContract           |
                          |    comboContractsList   |
                          |                         |
                          | btnPreviewReport        |
                          +-------------------------+
```

If I click on the Preview Invoice button, show all records from contract table where customer id (FK) is = to the id picked from the combo box.

If I picked contract from the radio buttons, the contract combo box would work, showing a list of contract id(s), running the report then would show you the record from the contract table where contract id = the id picked from the combo box...

Comment: There are a BUNCH of ways... your question is too generic.  Can you give some example of current content and what you want to change about it?   Do you want to change the content per specific customer?  specific type of transaction? what...

Comment: @DRapp , thank u and so sorry for the late reply..i thought everyone abandoned me....ok, so this is what i want to do. I have a contract form, which is connected to the contract table. in that form, there's a button to run another small invoice form. the invoice form contains 2 radio buttons labeled (customer & contract) and two combo buttons (also list of customers & list of contract id), obviously iam making two reports. now, if u pick customer from the radio buttons u cant pick contract.

Comment: and then the customer combo box would be enabled and usable. a list of customer ids come up and u pick one. there's a button "preview invoice" which when u click after all this will show (Or what i want it to show is) all records from contract table where customer id (FK) is = to the id picked from the combo box.

Comment: and if u picked contract from the radio buttons, the contract combo box would work, showing a list of contract id(s), running the report then would show you the record from the contract table where contract id = the id picked from the combo box. can you help me? please am at my wits end....

Comment: revised my answer for you again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've edited the message to hopefully better understand your layout of the form(s) with respective radio button combobox controls respectively enabled/disabled.  I think you'll need to draw up two distinct reports no matter what showing respective content, then call each one based on the radio button setting...  Such as in the "btnPreviewReport" object CLICK event... I've roughed-in on the sample...

```
if not empty( Thisform.radioControl.radioCustomer.Value )
   */ Customer radio button was selected
   xCustomerID = comboCustomersList.Value

   */ Run your Query
   select ... from YourTable where ... into cursor C_SampleCustomerData

   */ Run the report
   report form YourCustomerReport preview

else 
   */ Contract radio button was selected

   */ Customer radio button was selected
   xContractID = comboContractsList.Value

   */ Run your Query
   select ... from YourTable where ... into cursor C_SampleContractData

   */ Run the report
   report form YourContractReport preview
endif
```

Again, I tried the form as best from your description.

EDIT -- second comment clarification...

The nice thing about reports in VFP is they do not pre-require any hard DBF() in the data environment.  However, it would be good to have your data fields set to an Alias.Field reference you are EXPECTING to have.  So, if your querying of the data for the Customer report should always have the same expected alias result...

```
ex:
// pre-close in case the alias we want was already left open previously
use in select( "C_CustomerResults" )
select c1.*;
   from YourCustomerTable c1;
   where c1.ID = SomeChosenID;
   into cursor C_CustomerResults readwrite 

Then, in your report, have all your fields to something like

C_CustomerResults.FirstName
C_CustomerResults.LastName
C_CustomerResults.OtherField
```

This example uses an otherwise long alias name but just for clarification of handling.

I would do a similar for your "contract" results alias.  As long as that alias is in use, the report will run against whatever is the current table in use.  Nothing fancy, no other prep, no data environment settings needed in the report...

By pre-querying a sample of the data you would have in the report can help you in "roughing" the layout of your report.  Then, finish your form to run the query and show the report and you're done.

EDIT -- revised comment follow-up again

Yes... for your customer invoice with multiple lines, same thing... however your report has a header band for things you want to only show once at the top of the page, and a detail band where you would want to show content for your "each line item" of the invoice, and a report footer to show any totals.  Depending on complexity, you can add additional "Data Groups" in the report, but start with this now.  It sounds like you need to get your feet wet with something working first before you expand on it.

If VFP is your development platform, another website that has dedicated experts in VFP all the time is at www.UniversalThread.com.  They also support other forums, but in VFP, they'll get 100+ questions thrown at it a day...

Comment: the code makes sense and all...but how would the report know about the cursor we selected the data into...anything i have to do in the report itself? thanks alot :)

Comment: hmm...the following i did not understand,where does this code go?                                    // pre-close in case the alias we want was already left open previously
use in select( "C_CustomerResults" )
select c1.*;
   from YourCustomerTable c1;
   where c1.ID = SomeChosenID;
   into cursor C_CustomerResults readwrite))                                                              iam sorry, not very good with foxpro

Comment: ok, so this worked for the contract invoice because all i need is one record, but with the customer invoice i'd need more than one record to show on the report. any ideas?

Comment: @BFK, revised answer again per last comment